# How to configure GitKraken to ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: git

My .java files are encoded in ISO-8859-1. When I make some changes and visualize through GitKraken, I notice that accented characters appear � .

This is not a problem, even because this is only in the GitKraken view, not changing the file encoding.

However, if I stash a file, and then pop it, the file back converted to UTF-8, causing problems in my application. Converting all special characters to ï¿½

This is very bad, it occurred to me that I had to change in the hand several files that the GitKraken changed, it took me hours of work.

Is there any way I can configure GitKraken to ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being Gitkraken supports only UTF-8. There is a current comment in their Slack Channel https://gitkraken.slack.com/archives/C2DRKFLVB/p1539183842000100?thread_ts=1539161298.000100&cid=C2DRKFLVB

Comment: Okay, I'll settle for waiting. I thought it would be possible to change some configuration file and make it work for ISO encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to configure GitKraken to use ISO-8859-1 encoding. I also learned it the hard way. My German umlauts were damaged as soon as I discarded hunks.